# Nested Interface and Implementing class behavior

Tags: java, oop, interface

This is about `access specifier` for classes that implements nested interface. More details follow:

```
interface Fun{
    interface NestedFun{
        void nestedFunction();
    }
    void function();
}

class A implements Fun{
    class B implements Fun.NestedFun{
        //implements functionality
    }

    // implements functionality
}
```

What would be the access specifier for `class B` as we know that by default, nested interfaces are `static`. Would that make the class implementing such `interface` `static`?

Comment: No. And `static` isn't an access modifier, either.

Comment: It's the exact same situation with `Map.Entry` and `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks, made the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

All `static` means in the context of a class is that it is a nested class without an implicit reference to the instance of the outer class which created it.

Whether or not a reference exists in a class is down to implementation; interfaces aren't concerned with implementation.

Comment: so, I can not instantiate B as `new A.B()` in this case.

Comment: @AbhirojPanwar No you can't.

Comment: You can instantiate it either as `new A().new B()` (or `someA.new B()`), or with `new A.B()` if you make `B` explicitly static.